# Changing x-axis start and end value in LineChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Trying to implement a LineChart in my expense manager app.

Here are my entries from the debug window:

```
entries = {ArrayList@5297}  size = 5
0 = {Entry@5367} "Entry, x: 11.0 y: 0.0"
1 = {Entry@5368} "Entry, x: 12.0 y: -5.0"
2 = {Entry@5369} "Entry, x: 1.0 y: 0.0"
3 = {Entry@5370} "Entry, x: 2.0 y: 5.0"
4 = {Entry@5371} "Entry, x: 3.0 y: 0.0"
```

Here, the XAxis values represent the month of year and the YAxis values represent the net income that month.

Here is my code:

```
List<Integer> xAxisValues = new ArrayList<>();
//I add xAxis values as listed above

List<Float> yAxisValues = new ArrayList<>();
//I add yAxis values as listed above

List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        entries.add(new Entry(xAxisValues.get(i), yAxisValues.get(i)));
    }

LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Company Net Income");

dataSet.setColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    LineData data = new LineData();
    data.addDataSet(dataSet);

    final HashMap<Integer, String> monthMap = new HashMap<>();
    monthMap.put(1, "Jan");
    monthMap.put(2, "Feb");
    monthMap.put(3, "Mar");
    monthMap.put(4, "Apr");
    monthMap.put(5, "May");
    monthMap.put(6, "Jun");
    monthMap.put(7, "Jul");
    monthMap.put(8, "Aug");
    monthMap.put(9, "Sep");
    monthMap.put(10, "Oct");
    monthMap.put(11, "Nov");
    monthMap.put(12, "Dec");

    XAxis xAxis = lineChartMonth.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return monthMap.get((int)value);
        }
    });

    lineChartMonth.setData(data);
    lineChartMonth.invalidate();
```

But as you can see in this

[image: screenshot]

the xaxis values are always from 0-12 no matter what order they are in the List entries. I would like the x axis values be the last 5 months i.e. Nov (11), Dec (12), Jan (1), Feb (2), Mar (3) in that order. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

XAxis setup

```
 final HashMap<Integer, String> monthMap = new HashMap<>(); 
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
 SimpleDateFormat numMonthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

        // Get last 5 month

            for(int i=-4; i<=0; i++){
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
                Date date = cal.getTime();

                String dateOutput = format.format(date);
                String numMonth= numMonthFormat.format(date);

                monthMap.put(numMonth, dateOutput);
            }

     XAxis xAxis = lineChartMonth.getXAxis();
      xAxis.setLabelCount(5);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return monthMap.get((int)value);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. I want the XAxis values to be Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar in the line chart. How do I set the x axis values to start from 11 (Nov) to 3(Mar) for that? Right now it's from 0-12

Comment: @GaneshT I have made some modification in the code, please check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I fixed the problem myself. I will post what I changed as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So, here was the problem: I was adding XAxis values like this

```
List<Integer> xAxisValues = new ArrayList<>();
    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH )+1;
        xAxisValues.add(month);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
```

which gave me these values {11,12,1,2,3} and so the linechart assumed I had values for 13 entries from 0-12. Instead I changed the XAxis values to {0,1,2,3,4} with the below code made it so that there are only 5 values shown in the xaxis. Later I can map 0 to currentMonth-4 (Nov), 1 to currentMonth-3 (Dec) etc.

```
 List<Integer> xAxisValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = -4; i <= 0; i++) {
        xAxisValues.add(i);
    }
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        entries.add(new Entry(xAxisValues.get(i), yAxisValues.get(i)));
    }
final HashMap<Integer, String> monthMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = -4; i <= 0; i++) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        String dateOutput = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        Log.e("Current Month", dateOutput);
        monthMap.put(i, dateOutput);
    }
XAxis xAxis = lineChartMonth.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return monthMap.get((int) value);
        }
    });
```

Here's the [working screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VjZZ.png)